# How to add dinamically some personalized text + id attribute whit jQuery that count correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have various divs like this:

```
<div class="textwidget"><div>
<div class="textwidget"><div>
<div class="textwidget"><div>
```

I want the divs output like this:

```
<div class="textwidget" id="widget-1"><div>
<div class="textwidget" id="widget-2"><div>
<div class="textwidget" id="widget-3"><div>
```

I have this jQuery that **works great**

```
$(document).find('.textwidget').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id',[widget-] + i+1);
});
```

But adds widget-1; widget-11; widget-21 etc. I want only widget-1; widget-2; widget-3 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) method with a callback and generate the id value based on the index which can be accessed as the first argument of the callback.

```js
$('.textwidget').attr('id', function(i) {
  return 'widget-' + (i + 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textwidget">
</div>
<div class="textwidget">
</div>
<div class="textwidget">
</div>
```

Comment: I figured out, look my answer above mate

Comment: @SashaChirico :  check your console for  syntax error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

Comment: Is correct now, were missing the [ ], look to my own answer, thanks again to the quickly response :)

Answer (score 1):

It's about the hierarchy of the operations, using `width+i` will transform it's value into a `string` immediately, so if you add `1`, it won't add it as the `math` operation, it will just add it at the end of the string.

```js
$('.parent').find('.textwidget').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'widget-'+(i+1));
});

console.log($('.parent').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="textwidget">
  </div>
  <div class="textwidget">
  </div>
  <div class="textwidget">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add explanation mate.

Comment: Look to my own answer, I figured out with less code

Comment: @SashaChirico Less code? What do you mean with less code? Actually your solution is worse. I prefer normal parens.

Comment: You have console.log($('.parent').html()); that I haven't. And my solution is correct, but we can do in any way we want, but I prefer my code sorry.. (I like the normal parens too, but I see most times people using the [ ] parens..so I think is better..)

Comment: @SashaChirico I wouldn't provide you a harmful or wrong solution, I would use code above by myself, trust me.

Comment: @Rajesh I was editing my post mate, would be nice if you would remove your dv :C

Comment: @Kinduser Just an advice, its better to post a complete answer. Quality beats quickness. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh There are few people here who post answers with only few words and editing it every few seconds later adding content. And it's wrong indeed. But if you post a **working** code snippet first and then editing your answer to add explanation, I think it's not that bad (:

Comment: In my understanding both are wrong and will get dv from me at least. But if those few words explain the reason of issue, in my understanding its better than posting working code. We are here to help people and not do their work, so explanation will actually help them in learning and not repeating their mistake. But again its just my POV.

Answer (score 0):

when you do i+1 it is interpreted like a concatenation try this:

```
$(document).find('.textwidget').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id',[widget-] + i-(-1));
});
```

Comment: And how does that makes `-1` and `-2` and `-3`? Element index will be incorrect with this logic. Though you have answered the real reason for problem

Comment: Look to my own answer, I have resolve it with less code, thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score -2):

I figured out, the right code is:

```
$(document).find('.textwidget').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id',[widget-] + [i+1]);
});
```

Are missing the [ ]